# Capistrano - mark instances as pending during deployment to an ALB target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, capistrano3, elastic-load-balancer

I am deploying a Rails application to an autoscaled environment using custom tasks in my deploy files (basically I am using the Ruby aws sdk to select instances by tags matching my production environment and deploying to those instances)

Those instances are actually registered under target groups and my app distributes traffic to those TGs from an Application Load Balancer (ELBv2)

During my capistrano deployments, the `deploy:restart` task asks to restart the server (I am using Phusion Passenger) to use the new application. Since restarting can be quite long (up to 1min), I have added a custom restart `wait` option of 60 seconds to ensure my servers are restarted one by one so as to ensure continuous usage of my service.

However the only thing that is missing and makes the above delay useless, is that during this time my ALB keeps sending requests to those instances because they are not marked as "unhealthy" or "pending" in my target groups.

I have seen some libraries like https://github.com/thattommyhall/capistrano-elb unfortunately they are quite outdated and not made to work with ALBs and TGs

*One last piece of info : my capistrano deploy task actually deploys to several machines matching different roles :*

- *API servers (front facing, behind the ALB+TG as described above)*
- *Workers ans schedulers (those are not behind any ALB no special precautions must be taken)*

**So my (sub-)question(s) is(are)**

- Is it possible to flag an instance behind a TG as "pending" manually ? If not, then would an `deregister` followed by an immediate `register` achieve the same thing ?
- How can I, from a Capistrano task, do the above to the instances of the `:api` role, assuming the instances are all in the AWS cloud, with an IAM role, under one target group (actually it would be useful if I could get some tricks to support several TGs for the same instance)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently setting up autoscaling with lifeCycle hooks and will probably get to this later, but otherwise a possible solution (that I haven't validated yet) would be to

- deregister a target ([CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/deregister-targets.html)).
- (optionally) wait for target to be deregistered ([CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/wait/target-deregistered.html)).
- resume the passenger:restart command
- (optionally) register the target again ([CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/register-targets.html)).
- wait for target to be in service ([CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/wait/target-in-service.html)).
- Proceed with same hooks on next instance

The speed of execution would depend on the server restart time / health check efficiency. Maybe a better solution, if there are enough servers in production, would be to skip the wait times and ensure you always have a "window" of x servers online

ie. suppose you have 5 servers, that take 30sec to restart, you could possibly deregister-restart-register a server every 15 sec to make sure thre are always 2 servers up at any time (assuming the health checks are frequent enough to mark an instance as healthy within 15 secs)